# Is Devart Oracle provider support split query feature which is newly added in EF Core 5?

Tags: devart, ef-core-5.0

One of my projects is in EF core 3.1. This uses the Devart Oracle provider. Now I need to upgrade this project into EF Core 5. In a POC I found that using devart the split query feature is not working as demonstrated in the document. The code snippet is given below.

```
 var order = context.PURORDMAINs
                        .Include(p => p.PURORDDETs)
                        .AsSplitQuery()
                        .ToList();
```

The query is generated using `AsSplitQuery()` is like `FROM PURORDMAIN AS p ORDER BY p.ORDCODE ASC`. This is then only query generated in the console. But if not use `AsSplitQuery()` then it generates query like `FROM PURORDMAIN AS p LEFT JOIN PURORDDET AS p0 ON p.ORDCODE == p0.ORDCODE ORDER BY p.ORDCODE ASC, p0.CODE ASC`.

Am I doing something wrong? Any type of help is appreciable.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: From what you say I'd rather conclude that it *is* working. But then there should be a second query with split queries.

Comment: Exactly, but it's not generating the 2nd one.

Comment: Then there's a bug in de provider and you should report it there.

Comment: We cannot reproduce the problem in our environment, two queries are generated. Could you please send us a small test project with the corresponding DDL script via https://www.devart.com/company/contactform.html ?

Comment: There was some config issue in my project, so it had the above issue. Now it is working fine.